# How to use a simple ajax to edit a record in ror?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am a beginner to RoR. I tried to use a ajax to edit my record by add `remote: true` , while I click the edit link ajax function are not called.
Here is index.html.erb:

`<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_message_path(message), remote: true%></td>`

edit.js.erb file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#edititem').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
      url:'/messages/' + this.parentElement.id + '/edit/',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(){
        $('#edititem').append("<%= j render(:partial => 'messages/form') %>");
   }
});
});
});
```

Here is edit method in Contoller:

```
def edit
     @message = Message.find(params[:id])
     respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to @message }
     format.js 
  end
  end
```

Please help me to identify my mistake....

Comment: Try to add `format: :js` in path method arguments, like: `<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_message_path(message, format: :js), remote: true %>`

Comment: What you are expecting to do with ajax functionality

Comment: while I  click the edit link ajax function should to be called. @Ganesh

Comment: I think now it is getting called, right?

Comment: Now it's also not getting called, If  I click edit link, It doesn't display a Edit Page instead of It display a Show Page.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you click on edit then it triggers a `JS` request as you have written `remote: true` in edit link.

Here instead of a javascript onclick function, use `edit` action of `messages` controller which will respond to js request and then create view `messages/edit.js.erb` and write other javascript stuff here to render edit form.

here is an example.

```
$('#selector').append("<%= j render(partial: 'messages/form', message: @message)) %>");
```

This will append edit form without refreshing page.

Comment: Here is my edit method in controller:  `def edit
     @message = Message.find(params[:id])
      format.js 
  end`

Comment: have you added javascript code is `messages/edit.js.erb` file?

Comment: Why you are using `$.getScript(this.href);` instead, render partial for a form which will be used to edit a message.

Comment: I used render partial for a form to edit a message I got a following error  **NameError in Messages#index undefined local variable or method `message' for #<#<Class:0x007fcc95524428>:0x007fcc95401168>
Did you mean?  message_url
               @messages
Extracted source (around line #1):
1
2
3
4
5
6
              
<%= form_with(model: message, remote: true) do |form| %>
  <% if message.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(message.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this message from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>**

Comment: Please check the updated answer, you need to pass `message` variable while rendering form

Comment: Again ajax function is not called, here i upload my edit.js.erb file `$(function(){
$("#edititem td ").live('click', function() {
    $('#edititem').append("<%= j render(partial: 'messages/form', locals: { message: @message })) %>");
      return false;
});
});` Help me to identify my mistake...

Comment: just write following code in edit.js.erb `$('#edititem').append("<%= j render(partial: 'messages/form', locals: { message: @message })) %>");` and remove all other code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_message_path(message), remote: true%></td>
```

This link will redirect you to `edit action` of `messages_controller.rb`. Here, You need to define `respond_to` block.

```
def edit
  @message = Message.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @message }
    format.js 
  end
end
```

This will now response as per your action type. Please check and let me know if you have any query regarding this. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Even after i add `respond_to` block  ajax are not called. Help me to solve this problem...